# REST API documentation

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am new to django-rest-framework. And I wonder if this module give user self generating documentation of his API. What I mean is if drf provides a page on which I will have all my api methods listed (with required permissions, params, urls and description)?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the `django-rest-framework-docs` package:

https://github.com/marcgibbons/django-rest-framework-docs

Also the newer `django-rest-swagger` package, by the same author:

https://github.com/marcgibbons/django-rest-swagger

Comment: looks promising, i will check that :)